# Remove CKEditor instance after editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I'm dynamically adding CKEditor instances (on click event) to some elements of my page using JQuery.

**Problem 1:** if the elements were already clicked they already have an attached instance of CKEditor and this will cause an error when trying to create a new one.

**Problem 2:** I don't have an **id** on these **elements** so don't know the **name** of the CKeditor **instances** in advance. In this case they will be [automatically generated](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#name) following a progressive counter, like 'editor1', 'editor2' and so on.

So I can't remove the instances by name and removing all the instances on each click event doesn't seem a right solution.

**QUESTION:** I'd like to remove the CKEditor instance right after I'm done editing an element. Any other suggestions to remove the instances on a clicked element if it already exists (without knowing the instance name) before (re)creating it.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the following HTML:

```
<div class="foo">Hello!</div>    
<div class="foo">World!</div>
```

You can use such approach to dynamically create editor instances basing on `div` elements. Once the instance is blurred, it's destroyed but any subsequent click on `div` will create a new one:

```
function attachEditorToElement( element ) {
    element.once( 'click', function() {
        CKEDITOR.replace( element, {
            height: 100,
            plugins: 'wysiwygarea,toolbar,basicstyles',
            on: {
                instanceReady: function() {
                    // Focus the instance immediately.
                    this.focus();
                },
                blur: function() {
                    // Save the reference to element.
                    var el = this.element;

                    this.destroy();

                    // A new instance will be created if div is clicked.
                    // Note that this is a different element than the one passed to attachEditorToElement.
                    attachEditorToElement( el );
                }
            }
        } );
    } );
}

var divs = CKEDITOR.document.find( 'div.foo' );

// Create editor instances when div is clicked.
for ( var i = divs.count(); i--; )
    attachEditorToElement( divs.getItem( i ) );
```

---

The inline way:

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

function attachEditorToElement( element ) {
      element.once( 'click', function() {
        if ( element.getEditor() )
                return;

        element.setAttribute( 'contenteditable', true );

        CKEDITOR.inline( element, {
            plugins: 'floatingspace,toolbar,basicstyles',
            on: {
                instanceReady: function() {
                    // Focus the instance immediately.
                    this.focus();
                },
                blur: function() {
                    var el = this.element;
                    el.removeAttribute( 'contenteditable' );

                    this.destroy();

                    attachEditorToElement( el );
                }
            }
        } );
    } );
}

var divs = CKEDITOR.document.find( 'div.foo' );

// Create editor instances when div is clicked.
for ( var i = divs.count(); i--; )
    attachEditorToElement( divs.getItem( i ) );
```

Comment: Thank you, I must have mentioned that I'm using the __inline editor__, I guess the approach is a bit different, isn't it?

Comment: thank you, ok, almost there but this doesn't work. If I click on any `<div class="foo">` element the _inline editor_ will be created only for the first one clicked. All the other DIVs (of class `foo`) won't create an instance on CKEditor inline, I'm trying to figure out why looking at your code